# provethat for a polynomial p(x) of degree 5 or higher its splitting field is not a radical field extension of Q

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I am currently studying Galois theory and I would really appreciate a proof that for a polynomial p(x) of degree 5 or higher its splitting field is not a radical field extension of Q, where Q is the group of all the rationals. Any thoughts or ideas would be helpful. thank you. If you find any gramatical errors is because english is not my first language and I have difficulties talking it, I have tried my best through pages to make a good grammar.

Comment: Not true. There exist polynomials whose splitting fields are not radical extensions of the rationale. But it's not true that for all polynomials of degree at least five this is the case.

Comment: but im saying for a general polynomial equation, for example a general polynomial of degree 5 wich represents all polynomials of degree 5

Comment: There are examples such as $p(x) = x^5 - 1$ that splits in a radical extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\mathbb{Q}$. There are also examples of polynomials with non-solvable Galois group such as $x^5 - x - 1$.

Comment: #Tob Ernack. but im saying for a general polynomial equation, for example a general polynomial of degree 5 wich represents all polynomials of degree 5

Comment: Ah for you latest comment, the Galois group of $ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a, b, c, d, e, f)$ is also $S_5$ I believe.

Comment: #tob ernack. yeah exactly i'm asking for ax^5 +bx^5 + cx^3 +ex+f